# DocuSign API Get Envelope Status: Do Polling Limits apply to the Developer Sandbox?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign [Envelopes: listStatusChanges](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges) API to poll DocuSign for updates to envelopes. I'm currently testing this out in the Sandbox environment. The docs say that "you are not allowed to poll DocuSign more than once every 15 minutes" but I've been testing this every 2-3 minutes and not encountering any issues here.

Does anyone know if this 15 minute limit does not apply to the Sandbox environment? I don't have a production version to test against at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polling limit does apply to the sandbox accounts but DocuSign is more lenient about the limits in the sandbox platform since it is for development.

Your application will not pass the GoLive testing if it polls more than once per 15 minutes. See **Polling Violations** on [this page](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live-troubleshooting).

If your application's polling behavior changes after it is on the production platforms then our automatic monitoring will notify DocuSign staff about your app's violation. The staff will then determine the next step. In the future, actions such as suspending your integration key (client id) may be taken automatically.

**Recommended** Don't poll. Instead, use the DocuSign Connect webhook feature. If you send your envelopes via the API, then the webhook feature is included with all pricing plans. See the `eventNotification` attribute of the Envelopes::create call.

Comment: "the webhook feature is included with all pricing plans", is there a source for this / is this still true in 2021? On the API pricing page I only see DocuSign Connect under the "Advanced API" plan, but not the two lower plans.

Comment: The **Connect** (account-level webhooks) is only included with some pricing plans. The **eventNotification** attribute (envelope-level webhook) is included in all plans. To use eventNotification, you must create the envelope by using the API.